# How to add a Intellij project to netbeans

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, netbeans

I clone a project from a git repository, the project is created by Intellij Idea 14.0.3. And in my machine I want to use Neabeans 8.2 but the project could not be added. 
I tried `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to change the structure of the project to an eclipse project, but it didn't work.

Do you have any idea ?

My project is a maven based project.

Comment: What kind of project is it? Maven? Cradle?

Comment: it's maven project

Comment: How exactly are you trying to import this project and what is actually happening?

Comment: I cloned the project in my workspace, and I want to import it into Netbeans. what I have now is that netbeans knows not the project recovered

Comment: Try to open the project using the pom file. Maven is iDE independent. So easily can open the project by opening the pom file.

Comment: Did u try this. Any difficulties

Comment: Yes it's working now